# Odata feed not connecting in PowerBI or Excel

Tags: asp.net, excel, odata, powerbi

I have an OData feed setup in a asp.net web api app. The app uses Azure AD to authenticate so I was planning on passing the bearer token inside a PowerBI script as described here:

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Power-BI-Desktop-Unable-to-pull-from-OData-feed-using-Token/td-p/129714

The feed works fine when doing this through say Fiddler, passing a bearer token and calling it. But if I use PowerBi or excel it gives me this error:

```
DataSource.Error: Microsoft.Mashup.Engine1.Library.Resources.HttpResource: Request failed: 
OData Version: 3 and 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (Bad Request)
OData Version: 4, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (Bad Request)
OData Version: 3, Error: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request. (Bad Request)
Details:
    DataSourceKind=OData
    DataSourcePath=https://localhost:8401/odata/Persons
```

When I edit the data source permissions, I have tried anonymous access. I can't use basic auth or organisational accounts as they don't work with AzureAD. I have setup my controller like so using AllowAnonymous, though I'm passing the bearer token anyway and it works in Fiddler:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class PersonsController : ODataController
    {

        public PersonsController()
        {
        }

        [EnableQuery(PageSize = 20, AllowedQueryOptions = AllowedQueryOptions.All)]
        public IQueryable<Persons> Get()
        {
            return new List<Persons>
            {
                new Persons
                {
                    Forename = "john",
                    Surname = "smith"
                },
                new Persons
                {
                    Forename = "john",
                    Surname = "smith"
                }
            }.AsQueryable();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried something similar time ago with no luck.  I'll keep an eye on your progresses... :)